# How to delete a chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat

A few days ago I accidentally created [an unnecessary chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51554/room-for-george-a-strieby-and-t-e-d), and now I'm wondering how to remove it. Could anyone tell me what I need to do to delete a chat room, if that's even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely if you (and everyone else) quits chatting in it, [it will go away](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention) on its own.

Comment: OK, I get it, if no one posts on it for seven days it'll be automatically deleted. Thanks, Ted! You're always so quick to answer!